# create members automatically if they are used in construction

Tags: c++, templates, generics, boost, metaprogramming

Suppose I have a structure (or a class that I use just for storing) filled with `doubles`s. I make a constructor to assign to those `doubles`s:

```
struct Point {
  double time;
  double x;
  double y;
  Point(double a_time, double a_x, double a_y)
    : time(a_time), x(a_x), y(a_y) {}
}
```

It seems redundant to declare members in the class if they are already declared in the constructor. 
Is there a way to reduce these redundancy so that members that are used in the constructor are automatically public members of the class? also might be useful for other member functions.

this example is similar to the one on page 348 of [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726). So this is contemporary established style of coding.
Furthermore, I'm looking for a modern C++ style solution, meaning without pre-processor.

**Update (1)**
this struct needs to be used in the following way:

```
vector<Point> points
points.push_back(t0,x0,y0)
```

Comment: You can do it the other way around in some cases: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#member-init

Comment: What do you propose when class has mutliple constructors ?

Comment: Why do you want to declare all members of your class public that are used in the constructor ?

Comment: For structs this is granted but since you are referring to classes keep in mind that you should rarely use public on variables

Comment: @chris, I think your comment is the answer. btw, Prof. Stroustup is moving his website to http://stroustrup.com/, it will have the latest updates.

Comment: @Martin. i'm using it as struct, following guidelines of Bjarne's book. But it's a good point that sometimes I wouldn't want them to be public but that can probably addressed in some way.

Comment: @AdityaKumar, Good to know, thanks. My comment doesn't help in this example, but it might very well be the best you can get.

Comment: @kirill_igum: As a rule you RARELY want them public. Usually any class that has more functionality than pure data bundling should have private members.

Comment: @kirill_igum: Look at e.g. at herb sutters book on c++ coding guidelines for more explanation: http://books.google.de/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=herb+sutter+private+protected&source=bl&ots=ccSnLLdJSc&sig=ZUZu93ua-NDgaQA-Y3nL_LHJuqg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=M9QJUKfyO8T44QTSwe2rCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=herb%20sutter%20private%20protected&f=false

Comment: @Martin this is the case for pure data. In general I agree with you. but when I'm writing a quick prototype, it takes a lot of time to write all of gets and sets, and to use a proper oo design.

Comment: @kirill_igum, You might consider `emplace_back` for constructing the element in-place at the back if you have C++11.

Comment: @chris, please see update (1), your link works with constant expressions.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar, each constructor would have it's public variable. so there might be redundant variable. But I expects some kind of template-base solution where this would be solved during compilation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it is perfectly fine. However, if you want to just give default values, in C++11 you can initialize your members directly and you don't need a constructor:

```
struct Point {
  double time = 0.0;
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
};
```

Also, it looks like this struct is just a bag of data, if that is the case you can also use aggregate initialization which works without C++11:

**Example 1**

```
struct Point {
  double time;
  double x;
  double y;
} p = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

**Example 2**

```
struct Point {
  double time;
  double x;
  double y;
};

Point p1 = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

**After update**

You can use `push_back` like this with a flat data type:

```
v.push_back({t0, x0, y0});
```

Comment: @kirill_igum: I would remove the constructor and use `push_back` like in my example.